# Remove repositories from composer command line

Tags: command-line, composer-php

My project had a dependency that was on github, so when I installed it I ran

```
$ composer config repositories.vendor/package vcs https://github.com/vendor/package.git
$ composer require vendor/package
```

Now, I need to remove that package.
If I just run `$ composer remove vendor/package` the "repositories" section is still in my `composer.json` file.

```
"repositories": {

        "type": "vcs",
        "url": "https://github.com/vendor/package.git"
    },
```

How can I also remove the "repositories" section from the command line?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can run `composer config --unset repositories.vendor/package` to remove the entry from the `repositories` key.

However, this will still keep the empty `repositories` key. If you also want to remove that, you will have to use another tool that is able to parse JSON and remove the key yourself.